# Windows Store template is missing from Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I'm trying to follow the Getting Started guide for building a PhoneGap app for Windows 8.

The guide says to open the template: installed > template > other languages > javascript > windows store. But that template does not exist.

I'm on Visual Studio 2012 Professional Version 11.0 Update 1. Visual Studio Express was installed on this computer before Professional was installed but Express was uninstalled before Professional was installed.

How do I get that template?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The Windows 7 OS is not supported, so you cannot use those templates.

Quoting MS documentation:

> Windows Store app development in Visual Studio is supported only on Windows 8.1 Preview and Windows 8. Windows 7 is not supported. In addition, developer licenses aren't available for Windows Server 2012, so you can't develop Windows Store apps on that operating system.

[This also applies to VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm running VS express 2012 and found the windows store templates were missing from mine also. I found this page which points to Devenv commandline call to install templates so maybe try this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx

I'm interested to hear how you go with using PhoneGap and a windows 8 app together...

Answer (score 0):

even if you are using in Windows 8 missed the JS template then install this library 
before install this close you VS2012 express